# I'm trying to create a new line but it's not working

Tags: java, loops, newline

```
int exponent = Integer.parseInt(txtExponent.getText());
int base = Integer.parseInt(txtBase.getText());
int n = Integer.parseInt(txtExponent.getText());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sb.append( base + " to the power of " + i + "=" + "\n") //no new line
        .append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

I'm trying to create a new line for every new loop, ex to the power of 3 new line to the power of 4. But it won't work.

```
input txtOutput.settext (sb)
```

expected output:

```
-to the power of 4= 
-to the power of 5= 
-to the power of 6=
etc
```

Actual output:

```
to the power 4= to the power of 5= to the power of 6=
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not working?  How are you examining the contents of this StringBuilder?

Comment: its not working because it repeats the loop one after each other (5 to the power of 3 5 to the power of 6) instead of creating a new line for each (5 to the power of 3 new line                        
                                                                                               5 to the power of 4   )

Comment: So how are you examining the contents of this StringBuilder?  Because if you're running the code above, there's certainly a newline character in there.

Comment: Indeed there IS a new line.

Comment: your code is good, and `sb`variable  contains you `\n`, are you sure  `\n` is that you need to create a new line ?

Comment: Maybe the issue is on how you're looking at the result.  What do you **do** with this StringBuilder that you can see the string that you built?

Comment: You should show the code where you output the string.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there are new lines, as the below jshell shows (and even without adding System.lineSeparator(), in my case):

```java
jshell> int n = 3
n ==> 3

jshell> int base = 2
base ==> 2

jshell> StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
sb ==> 

jshell> for (int i = 1; i<= n; i++) sb.append(base + " to " + i + "=" + "\n");

jshell> sb.toString()
$12 ==> "2 to 1=\n2 to 2=\n2 to 3=\n"

jshell> System.out.print(sb.toString())
2 to 1=
2 to 2=
2 to 3=
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood when I output the loop in a text field in prints each loop on a single line instead of each loop on a separate line

Comment: What do you mean by "prints each loop"?  You have shown us a loop that creates one text string using a StringBuilder.  There is no printing going on in the code shown. **If** you print the built string, for example by calling `System.out.print(sb.toString())`, then it **will** have multiple lines.  If you're using the string to populate some "text field" (a concept that does not exist in the Java language, presumably it's some GUI thing)  then it depends on the "text field" as to what happens to the \n characters.  You probably need to show that code.

Comment: When you say "in a text field", are we talking Swing?  Java FX?  Some HTML thing on a web page?  If it's HTML, you might expect newline characters to get suppressed.

Comment: sorry I'm talking swing and I'm just confused why \n isn't creating a new line for each new loop number ex to the power of 3, then a new line to the power of 4

Comment: @Mr.Evan Please put the input, expected output, and actual output into your question as text.

Comment: I presume you mean it's a JTextArea in Swing?  The newline handling in that particular class depends on the first newline character that it finds in the text you give it.  So if you have a mixture of `"\n"` and `System.lineSeparator()`, you can find some of them being ignored.  Best to us `System.lineSeparator()` throughout, and not use `"\n"`.

Comment: @Mr.Evan I don't see what I could possibly misunderstand - in your code nothing is printed, or in any other way sent to the output. My code shows that if you print the resulting text inside the StringBuilder - it indeed got the newline characters. If it doesn't in your case you need to add explanation of how you output it and what the result is. I can see in other comments you talk about swing - you need to add exact code you use to output the text, so that there's no need to guess what you mean and what are you trying to do.